# c++ Is there any windows system program I could load my code in to protect my threads from being killed (CreateRemoteThread)

Tags: c++, winapi

I''m trying to find a way to prevent players from killing my process/threads. To achieve that, I'm planning to load code into another process that's present on Windows 7/8/10 and XP, if possible, but I'm not very knowledgable about Windows system programs.
Is there any program present on Windows 7/8/10 and XP that I could easily open a handle to and load my code with `CreateRemoteThread()`?

PS: I've never used `CreateRemoteThread()` before, so maybe I'm not aware that it's not intended for that. I have already found another method that's fully working anyway, but it requires the client to communicate with the server.

Comment: A thread that's created with `CreateRemoteThread` is no more difficult to terminate than a thread created using `CreateThread`. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, this question isn't going to get you closer to a solution.

Comment: actually it's fine i found a good solution yes it's not as hard to terminate i know but it's harder to find the player will be more confused  this is just another layer of security that I want to add

Comment: @Eliendrel this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). if you don't want a player killing your code, then don't give them access to it in the first place. Run the code under a different user account, or at a higher integrity level than the player's code.

Comment: That is not adding security, that is only obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

You have a thread which executes your implementation of antidebug but, users can easily terminate this thread.

Your solution is: to inject your code into a process which runs as SYSTEM so they can't kill it

I would not recommend this.

I would recommend that your antidebug code is ran in each thread independently and the threads keep track of each other, if one threads gets terminated or suspended the entire process should exit.

In addition you should use all the antidebug features provided by one of the many libraries, an example is [khaleesi](https://github.com/fengjixuchui/khaleesi)

Also consider packing your executable and if at all possible use vmProtect

Last of all your antidebug code can do a simple communication with your server, if the required message is not sent within the time limit, disconnect the player from the server.

Comment: *"inject your code into a process which runs as SYSTEM so they can't kill it"* - And now all an attacker has to do is hijack the program that injects code, and they have a free ticket to run anything under the SYSTEM account. That doesn't sound like a well though out strategy.

Comment: @IInspectable Try reading my answer again.  That's not my solution, it says "your solution", I am putting my answer in the context of his proposed solution.  I say "I would not recommend this".